# Android - Transparent course

Tags: java, android, textview, scrollview

I want to have such a transparent "course" like in the picture. How is it possible? There are many of these boxes on the screen and more to the bottom (when you need to scroll down to see the rest) I want them to become transparent. If you scroll down they should lose their transparence of course.
Can anyone help me?

[image: Example]

Comment: I guess its simply shades

Comment: Can you give an example to me maybe? :)

Comment: You can set the disabled state, using a State-List drawable.

Comment: Is the child added to a listview

Comment: See the fading edge property

Comment: That are just different, programmatically created TextViews which are in a LinearLayout und this Linear Layout is in a ScrollView

Comment: fading edge property looks quite good, just need to optimize it a little bit but thats the solution I think :) Big thanks Terril, can you post your answer as a seperate answer so I can accept it as correct? :)